# How to have one common filter for different fields in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index with 2 index pattern using alias.

Example:

```
Index Name: my_index
Fields: sender_name, receiver_name, item_name
Alias: my_index_alias_1, my_index_alias_2
Index Patterns: my_index_alias_1, my_index_alias_2
```

I have a dashboard with two data tables using my_index_alias_1 and my_index_alias_2.

Same person can also be sender and receiver but there should be *only one filter* to select the user.

Example:

If a user named Bob is filtered.

- my_index_alias_1 Data Table should filter by *received_name*
- my_index_alias_2 Data Table should filter by *sender_name*

I don't want do have duplicate index, so I think scripted field is the better option.

But scripted field can solve this only when I can access the *alias name* using `doc_value`, so then I can write condition like the below Pseudocode

```
if doc['_alias'].value=='my_index_alias_1' then doc['received_name'].value
if doc['_alias'].value=='my_index_alias_2 ' then doc['sender_name'].value
```

Comment: Since this is all one index `my_index`, in the end you want to search for Bob on `received_name` or `sender_name`?

Comment: @xeraa Yes but all with one filter control in Kibana "Select Name:", but selected option has to filter `received_name` in one index pattern and `sender_name` name in another index pattern. So then one table will show the Bob's received items and another table will show Bob's sent item in a same dashboard.